Incorrect output while trying to calculate SINE using Taylor series in C
Our professor gave us this assignment to calculate the sine of a given number using the Taylor series until 2 consecutive terms have a difference of less than 10-6, but since I'm new to comp-sci, I'm not really sure how to go on from here. I believe that the factorial is being calculated correctly.
I expected the output of sum to match the output of sin(x) the built-in libary
e.x. for input: 1.0, the output of sum should be 0.841471, matching the result of just inputting 1.0 into the pre-made function, but its output is 0.158529.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int val = 0,neg;
    long double sum = 0.0, x, prev = 0.0, curr, factorial = 1.0;
    printf("Type X:\n");
    scanf("%Lf",&x);
    curr = x;
    while (fabs(curr- prev) >= 0.000001){
        val++;
 
        prev = curr;
        factorial *= (2*val) * (2*val+1);

        curr = (pow(x, 2*val+1))/factorial;
 
        if (val % 2 == 1)
            neg = -1;
        else
            neg = 1;
        sum += neg*curr;     
    }
    printf("taylor series sinx:%Lf\n", sum);
    printf("math library sinx:%lf\n", sin(x));
    return 0;
}


You set curr = x; and don't set sum = x; as well.
That's obvious when you print the operations:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int val = 0, neg;
    long double sum = 0.0, x, prev = 0.0, curr, factorial = 1.0;
    printf("Type X:\n");
    scanf("%Lf", &x);
    curr = x;
    while (fabsl(curr - prev) >= 0.000001)
    {
        val++;

        prev = curr;
        factorial *= (2 * val) * (2 * val + 1);

        curr = (powl(x, 2 * val + 1)) / factorial;

        if (val % 2 == 1)
            neg = -1;
        else
            neg = 1;
        sum += neg * curr;
        printf("val = %2d: neg = %+2d; factorial = %12.0Lf; term = %15.9Le; "
               "old = %15.9Le; new = %15.9Le\n",
               val, neg, factorial, curr, prev, sum);
    }
    printf("Taylor series sinx: %Lf\n", sum);
    printf("math library sinx:  %Lf\n", sinl(x));
    return 0;
}

which produces:
Type X:
1
val =  1: neg = -1; factorial =            6; term = 1.666666667e-01; old = 1.000000000e+00; new = -1.666666667e-01
val =  2: neg = +1; factorial =          120; term = 8.333333333e-03; old = 1.666666667e-01; new = -1.583333333e-01
val =  3: neg = -1; factorial =         5040; term = 1.984126984e-04; old = 8.333333333e-03; new = -1.585317460e-01
val =  4: neg = +1; factorial =       362880; term = 2.755731922e-06; old = 1.984126984e-04; new = -1.585289903e-01
val =  5: neg = -1; factorial =     39916800; term = 2.505210839e-08; old = 2.755731922e-06; new = -1.585290154e-01
val =  6: neg = +1; factorial =   6227020800; term = 1.605904384e-10; old = 2.505210839e-08; new = -1.585290152e-01
Taylor series sinx: -0.158529
math library sinx:  0.841471

The output of the first calculation shows the error.  The fix is to set sum (as well as curr) to x:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int val = 0, neg;
    long double sum = 0.0, x, prev = 0.0, curr, factorial = 1.0;
    printf("Type X:\n");
    scanf("%Lf", &x);
    sum = curr = x;
    while (fabsl(curr - prev) >= 0.000001)
    {
        val++;

        prev = curr;
        factorial *= (2 * val) * (2 * val + 1);

        curr = (powl(x, 2 * val + 1)) / factorial;

        if (val % 2 == 1)
            neg = -1;
        else
            neg = 1;
        sum += neg * curr;
        printf("val = %2d: neg = %+2d; factorial = %12.0Lf; term = %15.9Le; "
               "old = %15.9Le; new = %15.9Le\n",
               val, neg, factorial, curr, prev, sum);
    }
    printf("Taylor series sinx: %Lf\n", sum);
    printf("math library sinx:  %Lf\n", sinl(x));
    return 0;
}

Output:
Type X:
1
val =  1: neg = -1; factorial =            6; term = 1.666666667e-01; old = 1.000000000e+00; new = 8.333333333e-01
val =  2: neg = +1; factorial =          120; term = 8.333333333e-03; old = 1.666666667e-01; new = 8.416666667e-01
val =  3: neg = -1; factorial =         5040; term = 1.984126984e-04; old = 8.333333333e-03; new = 8.414682540e-01
val =  4: neg = +1; factorial =       362880; term = 2.755731922e-06; old = 1.984126984e-04; new = 8.414710097e-01
val =  5: neg = -1; factorial =     39916800; term = 2.505210839e-08; old = 2.755731922e-06; new = 8.414709846e-01
val =  6: neg = +1; factorial =   6227020800; term = 1.605904384e-10; old = 2.505210839e-08; new = 8.414709848e-01
Taylor series sinx: 0.841471
math library sinx:  0.841471

Note that I used long double functions fabsl(), powl(), sinl() to match the long double arguments (in both variants of the code).  It's as well to be self-consistent, though the calculation could use double variables and functions and produce the same output.

In this case, you could also make it a bit simpler by setting the value of neg first (-1, or 1), and then simply alternating it with neg *= -1 in every step (before or after sum += neg * curr depending on the initial value).

Although this is a faithful rework of OP's code, would it be beneficial [speedwise] to maintain a "partial" numerator (similar to the the stepwise update of factorial) for the x^n term rather than calling pow* on each iteration? That is: long double xn = 1.0, x2 = x * x; and then loop on: xn *= x2; curr = xn / factorial;

Based on benchmarks I've done [on my machine]: SLOW: 0.000005254 FAST: 0.000000155 which is 33.897x faster

@skyzip — yes.  You could also wrap the sine calculation into a function, and separate the input from the calculation and printing.  You could also loop to calculate many values in a single run of the program, and so on.  I didn't intend to fix every possible problem.

@CraigEstey — yes.  And you could also make the changes I outline in my response to @skyzip.  I'm interested that the speedup is quite so big.  I also wonder whether a 'relative diff' instead of an 'absolute diff' would be sensible.  With sine, it probably isn't a big issue since sine(x) when x is close to zero is close to x, and when the numbers aren't close to zero, it matters less.  And I wonder about reducing large values of x by an appropriate multiple of π, and so on.  I wasn't intent on producing a production-quality function; I hoped to show how to debug broken code.

As the goal was "using the Taylor series until 2 consecutive terms have a difference of less than 10-6", Is arguable the wrong test as 1) the first time test is applied, only 1 term of the series has been calculated (makes a difference when x is small) and 2) better to use a constant of the same type: 0.000001L.

I've created an answer with the benchmarking code, derived from your answer. Please check this as it says that the "fast" version I described is faster than the glibc sinl function!? Anything you can see as I'd expect sinl to be tuned to be super fast.

@chux: I don't think the L suffix on the constant is a big issue.  The RHS constant will be promoted to long double by the usual arithmetic conversion rules when fabsl() is used.  The suffix is more explicit, but the result will be the same.  As to the testing, with a difference of 1E-6, there's no need for any extra iteration when x has a very small magnitude (1E-6 or smaller) — the first assignment is "accurate enough" (the next term is so small it doesn't change the result).

Agree the L is not a big issue.  Result is the same when x is not near either of the 2 values: 0.000001, 0.000001L, so usually the same.  Certainly the task simplified for a learner, yet using a *abs() to assess a FP function is something to unlearn later.

Preface: see my comments under Jonathan's answer.
I've reworked his version and added benchmark code:
Edit: Updated to support three float types: float, double, and long double
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define inline_always       static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef long long tsc_t;

#ifndef FLT
#define FLT     2
#endif

#if FLT == 0
#define FTYP    float
#define FF(_e)  #_e
#define xstrtod     strtod
#define FNC(_pre)   _pre##f
#elif FLT == 1
#define FTYP    double
#define FF(_e)  #_e
#define xstrtod     strtod
#define FNC(_pre)   _pre
#else
#define FTYP    long double
#define FF(_e)  "L" #_e
#define xstrtod     strtold
#define FNC(_pre)   _pre##l
#endif

typedef FTYP flt;

#define str(_t) \
    #_t
#define xstr(_t) \
    str(_t)

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#if _USE_RDTSC_
#ifndef __x86_64__
#undef _USE_RDTSC_
#endif
#endif

tsc_t tscbias;
double tscbogo;

// __tscget_clock -- timestamp from clock_gettime (nanoseconds)
inline_always tsc_t
__tscget_clock(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

// __tscget_rdtsc -- get CPU timestamp counter (raw)
inline_always tsc_t
__tscget_rdtsc(void)
{
    tsc_t tsc;

#ifdef __x86_64__
    u32 rax;
    u32 rdx;
    u32 rcx;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
#if _USE_RDTSC_ >= 2
        "\trdtscp\n"
#else
        "\trdtsc\n"
#endif
        : "=a" (rax),
            "=d" (rdx),
            "=c" (rcx)
        );

    tsc = rdx;
    tsc <<= 32;
    tsc |= rax;
#else
    tsc = _tscget_clock();
#endif

    return tsc;
}

// tscget -- get best timestamp
tsc_t
tscget(void)
{

#if _USE_RDTSC_
    return __tscget_rdtsc();
#else
    return __tscget_clock();
#endif
}

// tscsec -- convert tsc to seconds
double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec = tsc;

#if _USE_RDTSC_
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec *= tscbogo;
#else
    sec /= 1e9;
#endif

    return sec;
};

// tscinit2 -- initialize if using raw rdtsc
void
tscinit2(void)
{

#if _USE_RDTSC_
    tsc_t tscbeg = __tscget_rdtsc();
    tsc_t todbeg = __tscget_clock();

    usleep(1000);

    tsc_t todend = __tscget_clock();
    tsc_t tscend = __tscget_rdtsc();

    tscend -= tscbeg;
    todend -= todbeg;

    printf("tscinit2: todend=%lld\n",todend);
    printf("tscinit2: tscend=%lld\n",tscend);

    // get ratio of timestamp ticks to nanoseconds
    tscbogo = (double) tscend / todend;
    printf("tscinit2: tscbogo=%.9f\n",tscbogo);

    // get correction factor for tscsec
    tscbogo = 1.0 / tscbogo;
    printf("tscinit2: tscbogo=%.9f\n",tscbogo);

    printf("tscinit2: todend=%.9f\n",todend / 1e9);
    printf("tscinit2: tscend=%.9f\n",tscsec(tscend));
#endif
}

// tscinit -- initialize timestamp
void
tscinit(void)
{
    tsc_t tscbest = 1LL << 62;

    tscinit2();

    tsc_t tscbeg = tscget();

    // calculate the overhead of a tscget call
    // use shortest time to compensate for timeslicing/caching
    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 10;  ++iter) {
        tsc_t tscend = tscget();

        tsc_t tscdif = tscend - tscbeg;
        if (tscdif < tscbest)
            tscbest = tscdif;

        tscbeg = tscend;
    }

    tscbias = tscbest;

#if 0
    tscbias /= 2;
#endif

    if (tscbias != tscbest)
        printf("tscinit: %.9f %lld (tscbest)\n",tscsec(tscbest),tscbest);

    printf("tscinit: %.9f %lld (tscbias)\n",tscsec(tscbias),tscbias);
}

flt
sine_slow(flt x)
{
    int val = 0,
        neg;
    flt sum = 0.0,
        prev = 0.0,
        curr,
        factorial = 1.0;

    sum = curr = x;

    flt xn;

    while (FNC(fabs)(curr - prev) >= 0.000001) {
        val++;

        prev = curr;
        factorial *= (2 * val) * (2 * val + 1);

        xn = FNC(pow)(x, 2 * val + 1);
        curr = xn / factorial;

        if (val % 2 == 1)
            neg = -1;
        else
            neg = 1;

        sum += neg * curr;

        dbgprt("val = %2d: neg = %+2d; factorial = %12.0" FF(f) "; term = %15.9" FF(e) "; "
            "old = %15.9" FF(e); new = %15.9" FF(e)\n",
            val, neg, factorial, curr, prev, sum);
    }

    return sum;
}

flt
sine_fast(flt x)
{
    int val = 0,
        neg;
    flt sum = 0.0,
        prev = 0.0,
        curr,
        factorial = 1.0;

    sum = curr = x;

    flt xn = 1.0, x2 = x * x;

    while (FNC(fabs)(curr - prev) >= 0.000001) {
        val++;

        prev = curr;
        factorial *= (2 * val) * (2 * val + 1);

        xn *= x2;
        curr = xn / factorial;

        if (val % 2 == 1)
            neg = -1;
        else
            neg = 1;

        sum += neg * curr;

        dbgprt("val = %2d: neg = %+2d; factorial = %12.0" FF(f) "; term = %15.9" FF(e) "; "
            "old = %15.9" FF(e); new = %15.9" FF(e)\n",
            val, neg, factorial, curr, prev, sum);
    }

    return sum;
}

struct tst {
    flt (*fnc)(flt);                            // function pointer
    const char *sym;                            // function name
    double elap;                                // elapsed time
    flt ret;                                    // return value
    int ref;                                    // 1=reference func
};

struct tst tstlist[] = {
    { .fnc = FNC(sin), .sym = "sinX" },
    { .fnc = sine_slow, .sym = "slow" },
    { .fnc = sine_fast, .sym = "fast", .ref = 1 },
};

#define countof(_arr)       (sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0]))
#define ALLTST \
    struct tst *tst = tstlist;  tst < &tstlist[countof(tstlist)];  ++tst

// dotest -- run test on given function
void
dotest(flt x,struct tst *tst)
{
    tsc_t tscbest = 1ll << 62;

    // use best time to compensate for timeslicing
    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 5;  ++iter) {
        tsc_t tscbeg = tscget();
        tst->ret = tst->fnc(x);

        tsc_t tscend = tscget();
        tscend -= tscbeg;

        if (tscend < tscbest)
            tscbest = tscend;
    }

    // because times are so small the overhead of taking timestamps becomes
    // significant
    tscbest -= tscbias;

    tst->elap = tscsec(tscbest);

    printf("%" FF(f) " (%s) (ELAPSED: %.9f)\n", tst->ret, tst->sym, tst->elap);
}

// doratio -- compare two functions
void
doratio(struct tst *slow,struct tst *fast)
{
    double rat;
    const char *tag;

    if (slow != fast) {
        if (slow->elap > fast->elap) {
            rat = slow->elap / fast->elap;
            tag = "faster";
        }
        else {
            rat = fast->elap / slow->elap;
            tag = "slower";
        }

        printf("%s is %.3fx %s than %s\n",
            fast->sym,rat,tag,slow->sym);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    flt x;

    tscinit();

    char buf[100];

    printf("float type %d %s (%zu bytes)\n",FLT,xstr(FTYP),sizeof(flt));

    if (argc > 1) {
        strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        printf("Type X:\n");
        fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
    }

    x = xstrtod(argv[1],NULL);
    printf("X: %" FF(f) "\n",x);

    struct tst *fast = NULL;
    for (ALLTST) {
        dotest(x,tst);
        if (tst->ref)
            fast = tst;
    }

    for (ALLTST)
        doratio(tst,fast);

    return 0;
}


Here is the output for my system:

21:52:02 cc -O2 -o fix5 fix5.c -DFLT=0 -lm
tscinit: 0.000000022 22 (tscbias)
float type 0 float (4 bytes)
X: 1.000000
0.841471 (sinX) (ELAPSED: 0.000000026)
0.841471 (slow) (ELAPSED: 0.000000170)
0.841471 (fast) (ELAPSED: 0.000000031)
fast is 1.192x slower than sinX
fast is 5.484x faster than slow

21:52:02 cc -O2 -o fix5 fix5.c -DFLT=1 -lm
tscinit: 0.000000037 37 (tscbias)
float type 1 double (8 bytes)
X: 1.000000
0.841471 (sinX) (ELAPSED: 0.000000026)
0.841471 (slow) (ELAPSED: 0.000000510)
0.841471 (fast) (ELAPSED: 0.000000054)
fast is 2.077x slower than sinX
fast is 9.444x faster than slow

21:52:02 cc -O2 -o fix5 fix5.c -DFLT=2 -lm
tscinit: 0.000000022 22 (tscbias)
float type 2 long double (16 bytes)
X: 1.000000
0.841471 (sinX) (ELAPSED: 0.000000213)
0.841471 (slow) (ELAPSED: 0.000001839)
0.841471 (fast) (ELAPSED: 0.000000057)
fast is 3.737x faster than sinX
fast is 32.263x faster than slow

Note the "craziness". According to this:

the "fast" algorithm (using long double) is faster than the glibc standard sinl function!?!?
the "fast" algorithm (using double) is slower than the glibc standard sin function.
the "fast" algorithm (using float) is slower than the glibc standard sinf function.


Interesting! I wonder if the built-in sinl() handles (edge) cases that the Taylor series code does not?  For instance, what happens if you look for 15 decimal places instead of 6?  If you look at values greater than π?  I played around a bit with my solution, and got up to 9 printed rows of debug.  Regardless, thanks for the extra information.

@JonathanLeffler Updated the program to use float and double as well as long double. It seems that only the standard function for long double (i.e. sinl) is slower. The other two are closer to expected results.

In addition to improper initialization mentioned by others, sometimes it is good to
clearly employ the coding goal:

Our professor gave us this assignment to calculate the sine of a given number using the Taylor series until 2 consecutive terms have a difference of less than 10-6, ...

By 2 consecutive terms have a difference, I infer that to be that the difference in the magnitude of terms.

#include <math.h>
#define SK_SIN_TERM_DIFF_LIMIT 0.000001

/*
 * sine of a given number using the Taylor's series until 2 consecutive terms
 * have a (magnitude) difference of less than SK_SIN_TERM_DIFF_LIMIT.
 */
double sk_sin(double x) {
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_error_and_convergence
  // sine(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! ...
  double xx = x * x;
  double term = x;
  double term_previous;
  double sum = term;
  double i = 1;
  do {
    term_previous = term; // Save previous term value.
    i += 2;
    term = -term * xx / ((i - 1) * i);
    sum += term;
    // Since terms alternate sign, negate term_previous.
  } while (fabs(term - -term_previous) >= SK_SIN_TERM_DIFF_LIMIT);
  return sum;
}

///////////////  Test code

#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DBL_FMT "% -16.9g"

double sk_sin_test(double x) {
  double y0 = sin(x);
  double y1 = sk_sin(x);
  double fp_err = x ? (y1 - y0) / x : y1;  // Crude error assessment.
  printf(
      "x: " DBL_FMT ", sin(x): " DBL_FMT ", sk_sin(x): " DBL_FMT ", err: " DBL_FMT "\n",
      x, y0, y1, fp_err);
  return y1;
}

void sk_sin_tests(void) {
  static const double x[] = {0.0, DBL_MIN, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,
      0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0, 2, 3, 4};
  unsigned n = sizeof x / sizeof x[0];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sk_sin_test(x[i]);
  }
}

Output
x:  0              , sin(x):  0              , sk_sin(x):  0              , err:  0              
x:  2.22507386e-308, sin(x):  2.22507386e-308, sk_sin(x):  2.22507386e-308, err:  0              
x:  0.0001         , sin(x):  9.99999998e-05 , sk_sin(x):  9.99999998e-05 , err:  0              
x:  0.001          , sin(x):  0.000999999833 , sk_sin(x):  0.000999999833 , err:  0              
x:  0.01           , sin(x):  0.00999983333  , sk_sin(x):  0.00999983333  , err:  1.73472348e-16 
x:  0.1            , sin(x):  0.0998334166   , sk_sin(x):  0.0998334166   , err: -2.74780199e-14 
x:  0.2            , sin(x):  0.198669331    , sk_sin(x):  0.198669331    , err:  2.63677968e-15 
x:  0.3            , sin(x):  0.295520207    , sk_sin(x):  0.295520207    , err:  1.47844699e-13 
x:  0.5            , sin(x):  0.479425539    , sk_sin(x):  0.479425539    , err: -3.91908728e-14 
x:  0.7            , sin(x):  0.644217687    , sk_sin(x):  0.644217687    , err: -2.21759119e-12 
x:  0.9            , sin(x):  0.78332691     , sk_sin(x):  0.78332691     , err:  1.74428373e-13 
x:  1              , sin(x):  0.841470985    , sk_sin(x):  0.841470985    , err:  7.61946062e-13 
x:  2              , sin(x):  0.909297427    , sk_sin(x):  0.909297427    , err:  2.13462581e-12 
x:  3              , sin(x):  0.141120008    , sk_sin(x):  0.141120008    , err: -6.70507446e-11 
x:  4              , sin(x): -0.756802495    , sk_sin(x): -0.756802495    , err: -1.77408088e-11 


For large values of x, code should employ range reduction  (e.g. mod 2 pi).
#define TWO_PI (2.0 * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795)
x = fmod(x, TWO_PI);

That is itself another large problem to do well and not covered here.
